# Select with multiple paramaters with "mybatis-bean" component of Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, spring-mybatis

I' am trying to use Apache Camel's "**mybatis-bean**" to select some records with multiple parameters, but it turned out to be harder than I thought.

The mapper is defined as

```
@Mapper
public interface CityMapper {
@Select("SELECT * FROM CITY WHERE state = #{state}")
List<City> findByState(@Param("state") String state);

@Select("SELECT * FROM CITY WHERE state = #{state} AND country = #{country}")
List<City> findByStateAndCountry(@Param("state") String state, @Param("country") String country);
```

}

You can see from the code, I have two select query

- `findByState`: select with 1 param (state)
- `findByStateAndCountry`: select with 1 param (state and country)

**One param**

If I use my route to call `findByState` and set `NY` as the state in the body

```
            from("timer:myTimer?repeatCount=1")
            .setBody(constant("NY"))
            .to("mybatis-bean:com.netbase.camel.mapper.CityMapper:findByState").log("${body}");
```

You can see from the following log -- the `NY` in the body gets mapped to the only param `state`

```
2023-08-25 09:42:15.575 DEBUG 68665 --- [timer://myTimer] c.n.camel.mapper.CityMapper.findByState  : ==>  Preparing: SELECT * FROM CITY WHERE state = ?
2023-08-25 09:42:15.595 DEBUG 68665 --- [timer://myTimer] c.n.camel.mapper.CityMapper.findByState  : ==> Parameters: NY(String)
2023-08-25 09:42:15.617 DEBUG 68665 --- [timer://myTimer] c.n.camel.mapper.CityMapper.findByState  : <==      Total: 1
2023-08-25 09:42:15.620  INFO 68665 --- [timer://myTimer] route1                                   : [City(name=New York City, country=US, state=NY)]
```

**Two params 1st trial**

However, when I try to call `findByStateAndCountry` (with two params - `state` and `country`), I couldn't get the data in body mapped correctly to each param. I've tried using `Map` and `List` -- none of them worked

```
        from("timer:myTimer?repeatCount=1")
            .process(exchange -> {
                exchange.getIn().setBody(Map.of("state", "CA", "country", "US"));
            })
            .to("mybatis-bean:CityMapper:findByStateAndCountry")
            .log("${body}");
```

**Two params 2nd trial**

And finally, just before I gave up, I tried to call the mapper method like a Java method and I could inject header values into it.

```
        from("timer:myTimer?repeatCount=1")
            .setHeader("state", constant("CA"))
            .setHeader("country", constant("US"))
            .to("mybatis-bean:CityMapper:findByStateAndCountry('${header.state}','${header.country}')")
            .log("${body}");
```

My question is:

- Is my way a common way to bind the params in Camel?
- Is there another way to achieve the same effect?

In Apache Camel [official doc](https://camel.apache.org/components/4.0.x/mybatis-bean-component.html), it doesn't mention anything about this. It's really frustrating. After figuring out the correct way to do it, I would like to contribute to the doc.

Thank you